# Calculating distance (rows) between two same values on a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a VBA Code to calculate the distance between two cells with same values on a table. I just need the row difference between the cells which can be on different columns as seen in the picture.  I need only distance on the "Y" axis, not on the "X" axis. This code has the functionality and design that I need but it calculates distance on "X" axis too.

In the example picture below, in column B, **B5:Central** matches with the closest (down) **B12:Central**, and the distance ( the number of rows between them) is 6. And in **E1:250** it matches with **the nearest** **G16:250**, and the distance is 13.

[image]

The code I have is this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, f As Range
    Dim rowOffset As Long

    With Worksheets("gaps").Range("A2:F10") '<--| change this to your actual range of interest
        For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
            rowOffset = 1
            Set f = .Find(what:=cell, after:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not f Is Nothing And f.Row <= cell.Row Then rowOffset = cell.Row - f.Row + 1
            cell.offset(, .Columns.Count + 1) = rowOffset '<--| the "+1" offset results range one column away from values range: adjust it as per your needs
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I found to this problem addressing the issues I had in the codes offered.

```
Sub Intervals()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    With Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
            For Each r In .Cells
                Set c = .Find(r.Value, r, , 1, , , 2)
                If (c.Address <> r.Address) * (c.Row > r.Row) Then
                    r.Offset(, 13) = c.Row - r.Row - 1
                Else
                    r.Offset(, 13) = "na"
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Compute the rows

```
Sub main4()
Dim cell As Range, f As Range
Dim RowOffset As String
With Worksheets("gaps").Range("A2:F10") '<--| change this to your actual range of interest
    For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        RowOffset = "na"
        Set f = .Find(what:=cell, after:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext)
        If (f.Row <> cell.Row) Or (f.Row <> cell.Row) Then RowOffset = f.Row - cell.Row
        cell.Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1) = RowOffset '<--| the "+1" offset results range one Row away from values range: adjust it as per your needs
    Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

compute columns

```
Sub main2()
Dim cell As Range, f As Range
Dim ColOffset As String
With Worksheets("gaps").Range("A2:F10") '<--| change this to your actual range of interest
    For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        ColOffset = "na"
        Set f = .Find(what:=cell, after:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext)
        If (f.Column <> cell.Column) Or (f.Row <> cell.Row) Then ColOffset = f.Column - cell.Column
        cell.Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1) = ColOffset '<--| the "+1" offset results range one column away from values range: adjust it as per your needs
    Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

Or even better you can indicate both row and column in the cell:

```
Sub main3()
Dim cell As Range, f As Range
Dim Offset As String

With Worksheets("gaps").Range("A2:F10") '<--| change this to your actual range of interest
    For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        Offset = "na"
        Set f = .Find(what:=cell, after:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext)
        If (f.Column <> cell.Column) Or (f.Row <> cell.Row) Then Offset = (f.Column - cell.Column) & ";" & (f.Row - cell.Row)
        cell.Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1) = Offset '<--| the "+1" offset results range one column away from values range: adjust it as per your needs
    Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried both of them. The first one is what I really need. but It outputs many NA, -1, -2 ,1,0,2. I think it matches single digits with double digit numbers too. For example, it seems to match 2 with 12, or 20 etc. I seek an exact match and when the code finds it, it brings the number of rows between the main cell and target cell.

Comment: if you use main3() you will be able to locate exactly what cell matches to what cell. please give the two matches that does not work. (it works fine on my side and "na" is for no match found)

Comment: I prepared a sample data workbook https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoGkZUHlKui9gQ8NBaB1fllfYkXi Here you can see the results I get for main2, and the expected results  for the first two rows.

Comment: how do you compute 10 on O2

Comment: C2:3 and C13: 3, between them 10 rows.  I updated the picture in the question, it's shown there.

Comment: I see so actually you need the number of rows and not the number of col which is what you program is already doing, I will add a cleaned version as main4() to my answer

Comment: done, You will get the rows_values+1. your table is only half right. And I am sorry if this is rude: You should really still learn some basic of Vba before using functions like find/offset.

Comment: Yes, Main4 giving the results correctly mostly. but it also gives minus (-) results. I think the code checks data both  upward and downward. What should I do to make it check data only downward? please. When the code doesn't find any matching value at the bottom of the table, it will give NA result.

Comment: find methods is from `what:=cell, after:=cell,` you can play with it to your liking: if you have difficult requirements, you either need to dig in your program and understand what does what or contact a professional.

Comment: If don't wan't negative values then just add a function that make if(negative) then "na", if you cannot do that much by yourself you really seriously need to hire a professional.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I will play with the code a little, and try to find a solution for the minus results.

Comment: great, good luck.